# How many training and testing data should i use?

Tags: pandas, arima

I'm building my arima model and I have a quarterly data. The total dataset is 104 (1996-2021), now how many train data and test data should I use? Inorder to have an accurate forecast data. Thanks

Comment: do you mean, what percentage of data should best for test and train ?

Comment: @MUK yes, to have an reliable rmse

Comment: suggested ratio for test set is 0.2 or 0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ARIMA models, the rule of thumb is that you should have at least 50 but preferably more than 100 observations.

You can split the whole datasets at a ratio of 80 to 20.
80% for training and 20% for testing.